# Loopback android sdk fields are null

Tags: android, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have class Item which extends from Model with annotations ORMLite

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Item extends Model {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    public String id;

    @DatabaseField
    public String title;

    @DatabaseField
    public String details;

    @DatabaseField
    public String phone;

    @DatabaseField(defaultValue = "1000")
    public int position;

}
 ItemRepository repository = App.getRestAdapter().createRepository(ItemRepository.class);
        repository.findAll(new ListCallback<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Item> objects) {
                //here is my breakpoint
             }
}
```

Repository

```
public class ItemRepository extends ModelRepository<Item> {
    public ItemRepository() {
        super("item", Item.class);
    }
}
```

/common/models/item.json is:

```
{
  "name": "item",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "details": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phone": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": false
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Problem is when I retriving all data with `findAll`, I get list of null-fielded objects. In screen data is exists, but they are not at fields
[image]

Comment: It would be useful to mention where "@DatabaseTable" is coming from. Are you using some sort of ORM? Also, please show more code, especially all of your findAll call.

Comment: @barq I updated my question

Comment: I tried without ORMLite annotations also, didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer. When I add setters and getters, It worked!